# LocalStorage in Jquery, checkbox statement storing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Here is two issues:
First one: When I add data to my list in LocalStorage it's saving it and there is no problem, but when I remove data it's not storing this action in LocalStorage. How to fix it?

Second one: Also checkbox statements aren't storing in LocalStorage at all. How to fix that too?

Here is the code below:
http://codepen.io/ovesyan19/pen/chDgy

Comment: hey, you just took back my answer and then asking the same here ;(

Comment: Your answer maybe right but it's not working properly for me. I did it other way as you see and now something is working and smth is not. With your answer on my code,unfortunately, it's not working at all. But I didn't took back your answer. I appreciate your help!@AmitJoki

Comment: @Satpal, yes. I won't mind that ;) but it solved his problem and he took back my answer before asking the question here.

Comment: Maybe someone can help me there, editing my code?:)@Satpal, @AmitJoki

Comment: I don't see any removeItem in your code ? better to store each item in different localstorage item

Comment: I updated my post above@susheel

Comment: yeah I saw it but where it the code to update the existing code in location storage. you are just removing it from dom

Comment: I haven't got it cause everything I tried don't work.Can you edit my code your way to let me understand what you mean?@susheel

Comment: so have you an idea?@susheel

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bkjoz updated your fork only for deletion. saving complete html is not a good idea though. just store the values.

Comment: let me code you a better way...

Comment: ok, I'll wait , save/delete etc is working but checkboxes still not@susheel

Comment: are you here?@susheel

Comment: Code needs to go in the question. Your question cannot depend on 3rd party links to sites like codepen.

Comment: why not just use cookies?

Comment: 5 people have marked this question as duplicate but I don't see the actual answer at the pointed question. I don't see anything about localStorage there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**codepen link:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLtAs

**html:**

```
<form class="new_item">
    <input type="text" class="text_field" name="server_input" id="text_field" placeholder="Write a new task here..." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write a new task here...'" />
    <input type="submit" class="add_btn" value="Add" />
</form>

<div class="items">
    <ul id="tasks_list" class="sortable">
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
Array.prototype.remByVal = function(val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] === val) {
            this.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return this;
};

$(function() {
    $(".add_btn").on("click", function() {
        var task = $('.text_field').val();
        $("#tasks_list").append("<li><input class='tasks' type='checkbox' /><label>" + task + "</label><a href='#'>x</a></li>");
        $('.text_field').val('');

        /*Random Border Color*/
        $('li').each(function() {
            var colors = ["#f87c85", "#feb47f", "#3498db", "#b985ea", "#43d6b0"];
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
            $(this).css("border-right-color", colors[rand]);
        });

        /*Local Storage*/
        if (localStorage.getItem('todoList') !== '' && localStorage.getItem('todoList') !== null) {
            var existing = localStorage.getItem('todoList');
            var newitem = existing + "," + task;
            localStorage.setItem('todoList', newitem);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('todoList', task);
        }
    });

    /*Checkbox*/
    $("#tasks_list").on("change", "input:checkbox", function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).addClass("done");
            $(this).siblings('label').css({
                'text-decoration': 'line-through',
                'opacity': '0.3'
            });
            localStorage.setItem($(this).siblings('label').text(), "checked");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("done");
            $(this).siblings('label').css({
                'text-decoration': 'none',
                'opacity': '1'
            });
            localStorage.removeItem($(this).siblings('label').text());
        }
    });

    /*Adding New Item*/
    $(".new_item").on('submit', function(e) {
        //add stuff to database if necessary
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });


    /*Removing Task From The List*/
    $("#tasks_list").on('click', "a", function() {
        var _li = $(this).parent("li");
        _li.addClass("remove").stop().slideUp(300, function() {
            _li.remove();
        });
        if (localStorage.getItem('todoList')) {
            var items = localStorage.getItem('todoList').split(",");
            var replaced = items.remByVal($(this).prev().text()).join();
            localStorage.setItem('todoList', replaced);
        }
         localStorage.removeItem($(this).siblings("label").text());
        return false;
    });    

    function loadToDo() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('todoList')) {
            var items = localStorage.getItem('todoList').split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {                
                if(localStorage.getItem(items[i]) !== null){
                    $("#tasks_list").append("<li><input class='tasks done' type='checkbox' checked/><label style='text-decoration: line-through; opacity: 0.3;'>" + items[i] + "</label><a href='#'>x</a></li>");
                }else{
                    $("#tasks_list").append("<li><input class='tasks' type='checkbox' /><label>" + items[i] + "</label><a href='#'>x</a></li>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    loadToDo();
});
```

Comment: It's not working, check your own link

Comment: its working for me whats the problem

Comment: u dont have the done image

Comment: http://s7.postimg.org/jkf1y2yqj/image.png   This is what I take from your link

Comment: first clear your local storage completely and try

Comment: updated the codepen link.

Comment: Now everything is fine except the image of "done" which needs to be appeared if the checkbox is checked

Comment: what is your requirement..when you check the word gets striked off and tick mark comes ?? check the updated codepen link now

Comment: yeah, i use an image which comes over the checkbox when it's checked, now this image doesn't appear

Comment: in codepen it won't appear.. you don't have the correct image link in there

Comment: `.done:before{background:url("http://eip.kdcopy.com.tw/MotorWeb/Image/Mail/notification_done.png") no-repeat center;
}`

change this as per your needs

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLtAs

Comment: Oops, sorry, I was confused a lil bit. I added my link and everything is working. Thank you very much!

Comment: I has a small reputation so I can't upvote now, sorry, but it's definetely a correct answer and of course I accepted it:)